# While Rendering Grass Blender Crashed

Tags: rendering, particles, hair

I'm rendering my grass scene:
[image: Grass Scene]

Render Starts immediately blender prepares for render but right before creating image it crashes...
(and it is not only for this blend file when I create Particle System as hair in Blender Internal and assign materials & Blend Texture using Ramp it often crashes)

[image]

Comment: It's probably just your computer specs.

Comment: No while doing all kind of this stuff in blender cycles works.